# Можно ли сказать "с заботой к ~"?

Tags: предлоги

При выборе слогана для интернет-магазина встал такой вопрос: будет ли правильным слоган "С любовью к Вам, **с заботой к** Вашей коже"?

Я понимаю, что обычно мы говорим "забота о чём-то/ком-то", но в этом слогане хотелось бы выделить именно то, что "Вам мы несём любовь, а Вашей коже - заботу", поэтому хочется сказать "с заботой к". Но верно ли будет это? Или, может, нужно поставить тире после "с заботой"?

Буду очень благодарна за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

**С любовью к Вам, с заботой о Вашей коже.**

Из словаря

ЗАБОТА,  ж. 1. **о ком-чём.** Беспокойная мысль о чём-л.; сосредоточенность мыслей на исполнении чего-л., на удовлетворении какой-л. потребности. **З. о будущем, об урожае. З. о пропитании, о потомстве, о детях, о здоровье**.  2. Внимание к нуждам, потребностям кого-л.; попечение о ком-л. **З. о больном**.

Как мы видим, используется **только предлог О и предложный падеж**.

Но здесь и нет необходимости в другом предлоге, так как повтор обозначен в первой части: **с любовью, с заботой.** Этого вполне достаточно.

Comment: То есть Вы имеете в виду, что всё же правильно сказать "С любовью к вам, с заботой о вашей коже"?

Comment: Я именно так считаю. Можно, конечно, придумать предложение:  Мы  относимся к вашей коже с заботой.  Управление такое: относимся как? относимся к чему?  Потом забыть о глаголе и соединить зависимые слова. Получится такая искусственная конструкция, которую можно принять за правильную. Да только всё это не имеет отношения к вашему случаю. У вас вообще не предложение, а словосочетание, вот его грамматику и надо рассматривать. Так что я считаю вариант с предлогом К грамматически неверным. Но тем-то и хорош наш форум, что на нем есть выбор, так что решение за вами.

Comment: Русская стилистика речи имеет одну интересную особенность: мы воспринимаем сочетаемость слов на слух.  Если рядом расположенные слова не сочетаются друг с другом (в данном случае по падежному управлению), если они конфликтуют, то такая речь воспринимается как ошибочная. И это не зависит от того, какой смысл вы хотите вложить в вашу фразу. Этот принцип  особенно наглядно проявляется в сочетаниях подлежащего и сказуемого по числу или роду, когда целый ряд правил  регулирует выбор  комфортного для слуха варианта.

Answer (score 1):

*Грамматической* ошибки здесь *нет*, поскольку можно "**относиться с заботой к**" человеку и даже к вещи, однако правомерность предлога "к" держится на его сочетаемости с глаголом "относиться" (который в вашем слогане пропущен), а не с существительным "забота". Средний потребитель этот глагол мысленно не восстановит (для доходчивости слоган должен быть "тупее"), да и будь глагол на месте, не совсем убедительно звучит "относимся к вашей коже с заботой" ("относимся с заботой к вашей коже"). Если же вы измените предлог и получите "с заботой о вашей коже", то возникает вопрос: а что именно рекламодатель делает с этой самой **заботой о** коже потребителя, неужели "живёт" с ней?

Comment: Ничего здесь не пропущено, и восстанавливать ничего не надо. Это самостоятельная конструкция на основе словосочетания, а не предложения: любовь к Вам, забота о Вашей коже.  Вот, к примеру,  получите вы письмо, а в конце приписка: с любовью к Вам.  И что же, вы будете думать, какой глагол там пропущен?

Comment: Вот поэтому, если честно, не очень устраивает вариант "с заботой о вашей коже", потому что смысловой оттенок не тот, который мы пытаемся донести. Что мы как бы "относимся к клиентам с любовью, а к их коже - с заботой". То есть грамматически ничего вопиющего нет, верно? :)

Comment: @Sharon В письме может быть разное (как явно приписанное, так и подразумеваемое), но глаголом выражаемое:  "написала", "остаюсь", "всегда пребываю"... В рекламе такое не прижилось бы: чтобы подписью имитировать стиль письма, нужно перед этим что-то ещё написать.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, буду думать~